# CSS Animations - Animating a Zoom

Tags: css, animation

I have an HTML page with two divs. The divs represent steps in a wizard. After the user completes the first step, I want the second step to zoom in from the screen. As it appears, it naturally pushes the first step down. The information the user entered in the first step will appear below the second step.

I've created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/prxjgzey/). My CSS animations are defined like the following:

```
.first-initial {
  transition: all 1.0s ease;
}
.first-animation {
  padding-left:3rem;
  padding-right:3rem;
}

.second-initial {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.second-animation {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;

  animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-delay: 1.0s;
}        

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

My problem is with the `display` property. I can't animate the `display` property. But, if I don't set the `display` property to `none`, the first step is positioned incorrectly. How do I naturally push the first step down as the second step grows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand very well... you need show next input after click on "next button" right? See if is what you want:

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  var box = $(this).parents('.box').attr('data-box');
  $('[data-box="' + (Number(box) + 1) + '"]').slideDown(400);
});

$('.send').click(function() {
  $('.message').slideDown(400)
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
.message {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: #EFE;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-toggle">
  <div class="message">Thanks!</div>

  <div class="box" data-box="4">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button class="send">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="box" data-box="3">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="box" data-box="2">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="box active" data-box="1">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" />
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```